# Create a distinct matrix with random numbers between 1 to 75

Tags: c++11

I tried to create a matrix of random numbers ranging from 1 to 75 for a bingo game.

But, I am not able to generate distinct numbers.

The first row should have no from 1 to 15, second row from 16 to 30, third row from 31 to 45, forth row from 46 to 60 and fifth row from 61 to 75.

```
void creatingbingo()
{ int ar[5][5],values[5],i,j,k,n;


//creating bingo ticket
//initializing the values of ticket
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    values[i]=0;
}
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
    {
        loop:k=0;
        do
        {
            uniform_int_distribution<int> rows (((15*(i+1)-15+1)),(15*(i+1)));
            n=rows(randgenerate);
            if(values[k]==n)
            {
                k=0;
                goto loop;
            }
            else
            {
                values[k++]=n;
            }
        }while(k<5);
            ar[i][j]=values[j];//filling the ticket
    }
}
//displaying the ticket
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        cout<<ar[i][j]<<'\t';
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}

 An example of output which I got is:
 11      14      8       5       10
 16      26      24      25      19
 41      45      38      43      31
 55      52      60      53      60
 62      70      71      68      75
```

Comment: Here the no. 60 is repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way to do this: create an array `b` of 15 elements from 1 to 15. For each row `a[i]`, shuffle `b`, then copy first 5 elements of `b` to `row`, and add `15*i` to each element of `a[i]`.

Example working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

std::mt19937 rng{boost::random_device{}()};

std::vector<std::vector<int>> creatingbingo()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(5, std::vector<int>(5));
    std::vector<int> b(15);
    std::iota(begin(b), end(b), 1); //b = 1 2 3 ... 14 15
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::shuffle(begin(b), end(b), rng);
        std::copy(begin(b), begin(b) + a[i].size(), begin(a[i]));
        for (int& n : a[i]) n += 15*i;
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    for (auto& row : creatingbingo())
    {
        for (int n : row)
            std::cout << n << "\t";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

"Simpler" version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> //std::shuffle
#include <random>    //std::mt19937
#include <ctime>     //to seed rng

struct BingoTicket { //create a wrapper struct to return 5x5 matrix
    int grid[5][5];
};

BingoTicket createBingoTicket(std::mt19937& rng)
{
    BingoTicket ticket;

    // Create an array of 15 elements with values from 1 to 15
    int b[15];
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        b[i] = i+1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) //iterate each row of `ticket.grid`
    {
        // Shuffle b using a given random generator `rng`
        std::shuffle(b, b+15, rng);
        // Copy first 5 elements in `b` to `ticket.grid[i]`,
        //and add 0/15/30/45/60 so that row 1 will have values
        //from 1-15, row 2 from 16-30, etc.
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            ticket.grid[i][j] = b[j] + 15*i;
    }

    return ticket;
}

int main()
{
    // Seed rng
    std::mt19937 rng;
    rng.seed(time(0));

    BingoTicket ticket = createBingoTicket(rng);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            std::cout << ticket.grid[i][j] << "\t";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

(You can use `std::random_device` to seed `rng`, or use `std::chrono` instead of `ctime`)

Comment: Can u write this code in simple c++ language please @tntxtnt

Comment: I see you use `uniform_int_distribution` in your code so I guess you know how about C++ `<random>`

Comment: Thanks...But what is the use of the shuffle function here @tntxnt

Comment: And how the random numbers are not being repeated here although u have not used any function to check the repetion

Comment: Just like playing cards: for example, to pick 13 cards from a deck of 52 cards, first you shuffle the deck, then you pick first 13 cards from it. Here you shuffle `b`, then pick first 5 numbers from `b`. No need to check for duplicates because there is no duplicates in `b`.